# Check if div contains anchor with specific href value

Tags: jquery

Good Day

I want to check if there is a specific link inside my page that contains the following url:

```
http://mysite.com/category/products
```

I am using the following, but I don't think it is correct (since it does not work)

```
if $('#breadcrumbs a.category').attr('href') == "http://mysite.com/category/products";
    alert('It is here!');
```

The HTML Structure looks like this:

```
<div id="breadcrumbs">
<a class="category" href="">generated by php</a>
<a class="category" href="">generated by php</a>
<a class="category">generated by php</a>
</div>
```

The top link will be somewhere in this hierarchy...

thank you!

Update: [page](http://asksomeone.co.za/face-master-1-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr` method only returns the value of the first selected element, you can use `filter` method or `attr` selector.

```
$(function() {
    var len = $('#breadcrumbs a.category').filter(function(){
         return this.href === 'http://mysite.com/category/products';
    }).length;

    if (len) {
        alert('It is here!');
    }
});
```

Comment: cool man, thank you. But for some reason i does not work on my page...I updated my answer with a link on  the page I want this to work...

Comment: @DavidVanStaden Check your browser console man, there are 2 errors, 

`SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
[Break On This Error]  

0.f('<2'+'3 5="6/7" 8="9://a.b/e/o/g?d='+0.h+'&i='+j(0.k)+'&

face-master-1-4 (line 53)` and 

`TypeError: $ is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

$(function() {

face-master-1-4 (line 354)
`

Comment: sweet man. For some reason jquery was not included...It is supposed to be loaded by the Wordpress theme I am using...I uploaded it...Thanks for your answer, really appreciate

Comment: how would I replace the href in question with something else like google.com?

Comment: @DavidVanStaden You are very welcome. You can just change the `string`, or define a variable and use it instead.

Comment: @DavidVanStaden Yes `'www.somewhere.com'`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the attribute selector:

```
if ($('#breadcrumbs .category[href="http://mysite.com/category/products"]').length > 0) {
    alert("It's here");
}
```

Documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: none of these answers seems to work, yours included. and the url is right, I checked in the browser...(inspect element)

Comment: How about now, without the 'a' in the selector?

Comment: @DavidVanstaden Then surely you are not loading jquery library first.

Comment: No, I though it was included in the wordpress theme I am using, since the nivo slider must obviously use it...But it seems like it does not load on the pages I want to use this function on...Thnk you for your answer, appreciate

Comment: how would I replace the href in question with something else like google.com?

Answer (score 1):

Try shorter:

```
($('[href="http://mysite.com/category/products"]').length > 0) ? alert('Yes there are') : alert('oops');
```

#### [Tryout in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ces64/)

Comment: how would I replace the href in question with something else like google.com?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#breadcrumbs').click(function(){

 $(this).children('a').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('href')=="your url")
        .....
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if($('#breadcrumbs a.category').attr('href') == "http://mysite.com/category/products")
   {
       alert('It is here!');
   }    
});
```

Comment: @DavidVanStaden , ya ofcourse it does not give alert , it does give if it does find specific url as we declared.

Comment: have you include jquery library in your page ?

Comment: No, I though it was included in the wordpress theme I am using, since the nivo slider must obviously use it...But it seems like it does not load on the pages I want to use this function on...Thnk you for your answer